# How to create a stampcard type layout?

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-relativelayout

Im trying to create a stampcard system on my application but when its coming to laying out the stamps (they wil be invisable untill requested and shoud be spaced evenly in 2xrows of 3),

I cant get the view to sit right, I want the stamps to appear evenly over an Image view but it just wont happen, I tried to get my linear layout that will hold the 2 rows to stretch to the relative view ( who's size is set by the stampcard ImageView) so i could space them out evenly using their weight but it wouldn't stretch it would allways wrap the content any help would be appreciated.

The layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_fragment_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/home_page_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|fill_vertical"
    android:text="@string/home_fragment_title"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/stamp_card_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/home_page_title"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/the_stamp_card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/stamp_card" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/row_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/stamp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/stamp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/scanBtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/stamp_card_layout"
    android:background="@drawable/brown_btn"
    android:text="Scan?"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="23sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="normal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Result:

[image: Result of the layout]

I don't know what to do as they have to be over the image and stay relative to the stampcard and the only way I know how was using a relative layout and it is being designed for api 8 so it has to be simple :/

thanks in advanced!

Comment: Your linear layout is probably wrapping content because it's parent relative layout height is set to `wrap_content`

Comment: ImageView can have both a background and an image. Let each circle and stamp be one ImageView and you won't have to worry about aligning two different sets of views.

Comment: Karakuri- How would that work with six individual stamps(the cups) going on it? can it have multiple images attached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came to is to just have multiple Stampcard images each with a one more stamp than the last and to cycle though them.